# Filebeat -> Logstash indexing documents twice

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok, filebeat

I have Nginx logs being sent from Filebeat to Logstash which is indexing them into Elasticsearch.

Every entry gets indexed twice. Once with the correct grok filter and then  again with no fields found except for the "message" field.

This is the logstash configuration.

**02-beats-input.conf**

```
input {
beats {
    port            => 5044
    ssl             => false
    }
}
```

**11-nginx-filter.conf**

```
filter {
    if [type] == "nginx-access" {
        grok {
            patterns_dir => ['/etc/logstash/patterns']
            match => {"message" => "%{NGINXACCESS}"
        }
        date {
            match => [ "timestamp", "dd/MMM/YYYY:HH:mm:ss Z", "d/MMM/YYYY:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
        }
    }
}
```

**Nginx Patterns**

```
NGUSERNAME [a-zA-Z\.\@\-\+_%]+
NGUSER %{NGUSERNAME}
NGINXACCESS %{IPORHOST:clientip}\s+%{NGUSER:ident}\s+%{NGUSER:auth}\s+\[%{HTTPDATE:timestamp}\]\s+\"%{WORD:verb}\s+%{URIPATHPARAM:request}\s+HTTP/%{NUMBER:httpversion}\"\s+%{NUMBER:response}\s+(?:%{NUMBER:bytes}|-)\s+(?:\"(?:%{URI:referrer}|-)\"|%{QS:referrer})\s+%{QS:agent}
```

**30-elasticsearc-output.conf**

```
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["elastic00:9200", "elastic01:9200", "elastic02:9200"]
        manage_template => false
        index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
        document_type => "%{[@metadata][type]}"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Check your filebeat configuration!**

During setup I had accidentally un-commented and configured the `output.elasticsearch` section  of the `filebeat.yml`.

I then also configured the `output.logstash` section of the configuration but forgot to comment out the elasticsearch output section.

This caused one entry to be sent to logstash where it was grok'd and another one to be sent directly to elasticsearch.